# Icon file not opening after being converted with Pillow

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am trying to convert my PNG to Icon but when i convert it paint is unable to open it saying invalid bitmap i have put the code that isn't working below, i am using python3 with pillow and tkinter

```
def png_to_ico():
global im1
import_filename = fd.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("PNG File",'.png')])

if import_filename.endswith(".png"):
    im1 = Image.open(import_filename)
    im1.resize((32,32))
    imgg = fd.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".ico")
    im1.save(imgg)
```

Comment: Please include the actual error message in your question, and fix the indentation in the code.

Comment: I have same issue on some PNG images but not on other PNG images.  So it may be an issue on Pillow module.  BTW `im1.resize((32,32))` will not update the image *inplace*, you need to save the result like `im1 = im1.resize((32,32))`.

Comment: Try adding `bitmap_format='bmp')` in `im1.save(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

adding bitmap_format='bmp') in im1.save() fixed it for me Thanks